# jquery get children by attribute

Tags: jquery

This code is returning an empty array when I run it even though there is a div with the attribute [data-directory] in the container.

`$(container).children( '[data-directory]' )`

container is valid, and the children are there when I log $(container), I'm not sure why it isn't pulling the child that is there though.

Comment: please provide your html markup

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: are you sure $(container)  is valid ? shouldnt you add a # or a .

Comment: Works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/GLYyQ/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

please check to see whether `container` is a valid and exists if it does. then
probably `$(container).find( '[data-directory]' )` would do

.children would only look in the immediate `children`. where as `.find` will go through all the descendants which i think is what you want